# How to use different MongoDB databases in Spring during JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit, spring-test

I'm writing tests for Spring Boot (2.0) with JUnit5 and I need to use a different DB to run unit tests. How can I know, if my Spring app is being started by JUnit or not?
I'm planning to use this in `AbstractMongoConfiguration` for getting different `MongoClient` instances on `mongoClient()` method.
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use application-test.properties for providing mongo related properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have profile specific mongo properties like (URI) for test,dev,prod etc.

Sample test class (Updated for Junit5)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class SampleTest {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    //.....  Some Test methods goes here .... 

}
```

In above case we are providing a profile named **test** as ActiveProfiles. So by default two properties from classpath (resources) will be picked one will be `application.properties` and other will be `application-test.properties`. And what we will be doing is, we extract all db related configuration to their profile counterpart of application.properties.

My resources folder will contain

\resources

-- application.properties

-- application-dev.properties

-- application-prod.properties

-- application-qa.properties

-- application-test.properties

**applicaion-test.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<test db ip config goes here>/test_app_db
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<dev ip>/app_db
```

And so on, different mongo bean can be controlled by using profiles specific config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP asked about JUnit 5, not JUnit 4. Thus, `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` has to be used instead of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, and the `@Test` annotation needs to be `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was just focusing on adding ActiveProfiles. Will edit according to Junit 5.